# Ruby - how to write console input to file

Tags: ruby

I want to write a simple program, that writes console input to file with name i entered.

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
of = File.open(file_name, 'w')

while a = gets.chomp
  puts a
  of.puts a
end
```

# ruby write_script.rb file_name.txt

returns: `main: undefined method chomp for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

**update:**

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
File.open(file_name, 'w') do |file|
  while (a = gets)
    print a
    file.write a
  end
end
```

After executing this code - program terminates at start and empty file creates.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me :

```
begin
  File.open(ARGV.shift, 'w') do |f|
    while a = gets.chomp
      p a
      break if a == 'exit'
      f.puts a
    end
  end
rescue SignalException
  puts
  puts "#Completed#"
  exit
end
```

It should be noted that I'm using `ARG.shift` instead of `ARG[0]` because when using the latter `gets` will access whatever is in `ARG` before moving on the `STDIN`. `ARG.shift` removes the original argument.

Comment: Beatiful solution and just i had problem with ctr-c. Thank you)

Comment: That's normal since by interrupting you are throwing an error. If you want a clean finish even when using ctr-c you need to catch that error . I've updated the above code to catch it.

Comment: To finish cleanly on OS X or *nix, ctrl-d.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the problem lies in the fact, that `puts` does some stuff behind the scenes. Specifically, **if there is a file name as a command line argument**, `gets` reads the next line from that file (see these docs [Ruby docs, Kernel:gets](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Kernel%3agets)).

So, if a one line script:

```
puts gets
```

...gets called with CLI arguments like this `ruby onelinescript.rb some_file.txt`, it will print the first line of `some_file.txt`.

The problem in your case, I think, is that you open the file from the CLI argument list first for writing and then implicitly try to open it for reading with `gets`, which doesn't work. To fix that, you should explicitly state the IO object you call `gets` on:

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
of = File.open(file_name, 'w')

while a = STDIN.gets.chomp
  puts a
  of.puts a
end
```

P. S. In case I am wrong, please don't hesitate to point that out.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be true

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `chomp` as `chop` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The method here is `chomp`, which strips a string (taken from stdin by `gets()`) from the trailing newline character `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
file_name = ARGV[0]
of = File.open(file_name, 'w')

while a = STDIN.gets
  print a
  of.write a
end
of.close
```

Your problem is that gets returns nil when you get to the end of stdin.

Comment: Sorry , my iPhone totally makes it impossible to format code properly, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i tried this by myself, after executing that code with **ruby write_script.rb file_name.txt** the program terminates and empty file **file_name.txt** creates

Comment: Note: you must close the file at the end of the program! Best to use the block form of File.open (see my answer).

Comment: Oops!  I added a call to `of.close`.  That will probably fix the problem.

Comment: I also changed my answer to use `STDIN.gets`.  Thanks jst!